# WorkFlow email trigger issue

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-designer

I have 2 list

- User_List
- Manager list

in the user list- people will enter the required details based the form. i have used the Sharepoint designer workflow to copy the content from the user list to the Manger list using the "Create List item" and it successfully creates all the items in the manger list. i have set the workflow to run"automatically start the workflow when a item is created" for the User_list

next workflow runs on the User_list and copies all the content item  to "Manger list". i have a created another workflow on the Manger list to send an email to the manager with the link to edit the list which was copied. i have set the workflow to run "automatically start the workflow when a item is created"

but the workflow is not automatically running. i had to start workflow manually.

please help me, if you have any suggestion

i have paste the pic below[image: User_List_Workflow]

[image: Manager_list Workflow]